# manipulating indexes

Tags: c#

When my program runs it outputs the following error:

A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0x11d4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The thread '' (0xdbc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The program '[2868] Filereader m 15062012.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Why don't you tell us what the size of noise, length, td, and m actually *are* in the code where it blows up. That would *really* helpful.

Comment: thanks. i will provide more information

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I activated the 'Break when exception is Common Language Runtime Exceptions' - which can be accessed from the debug menu, then select exception, then activate thrown for 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions'. When the program run, it pointed to the exact location where the problem had occured.

Apparently, this was a code which was redundant as far as my program was concerned. So I deleted those lines. Thanks tp Tim Schmelter, aquinas and all those who asked me to run in debug mode. Appreciated!!